# template definitions syntax

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Short question, are these definitions same?

1.

```
    template<class T1>
    template<class T2>
    void function(T1 *a, T2*b);
```

2.

```
    template<class T1,class T2>
    void function(T1 *a, T2*b);
```

Comment: No, the first one doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not the same.  The first case won't compile as a free function([live example](https://ideone.com/gNPavH)).  Normally you would do the first case when you have a template class and you have a function in it that takes another template parameter

```
template <typename T1>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T2>
    void function(T1 *a, T2*b);
};

template<class T1>
template<class T2>
void Foo<T1>::function(T1 *a, T2*b);
```

Your second example is just fine as a function with two template parameters.